# Flutter: launcher icon base on phone theme

Tags: android, flutter, appicon, flutter-launcher-icons

I need to make different app launcher icons for Ios and Android based on system theme.
Is it possible to make launcher icons for:
Ios: light/dark
Android: light/dark?